# mongodb aggregation: get all values for the particular field in list

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation

I have collections like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "religion": "south",
    "tested": true,
    "fruit": "orange",
    "created_at": 2211123333
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "religion": "north",
    "tested": false,
    "fruit": "apple",
    "created_at": 223444433
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "religion": "north",
    "tested": true,
    "fruit": "orange",
    "created_at": 234567876
  }
]
```

if religion is south and tested is true then get all the values of fruits in list.

tried:

```
pipeline = [{"$match": {"$and": [{"religion": "south"}, {"tested": true}]}}, {}{"$project": {"fruit": 1, "_id": 0}}]
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline).to_list(length=None)
```

getting result as : `[{"fruit": "orange"}, {"fruit": "apple"}]`

but result should be like: `{"fruit" : ["orange", "apple"]}`

Comment: There's only one document where "religion is south and tested is true".  Is your example collection correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$group`, `$addToSet` and using`$cond` you don't need the `$match` stage

test it at [mongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M5rdCPv82VZ)

```
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "fruit": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$religion",
                    "south"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$tested",
                    true
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "$fruit",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      fruit: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Probably better to use `$addToSet` here instead of `$push`.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert yes you're right in case the author don't want to get duplicate data

Comment: I found this question while just wanting to see how many different values existed for one of the fields in my collection. The following 2-stage grouping worked for me fast (I ran this within MongoDB Compass): `[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
    },
  },
  {
    $group:
      {
        _id: null,
        types: {
          $addToSet: "$_id",
        },
      },
  },
]`